# Terraform plan is giving error in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run terraform script in jenkins pipeline. The "terraform plan" command is showing error

> 1mError asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - provider.aws: plugin exited before we could connect

The terraform script contain vars.tf & iam.tf

iam.tf

```
provider "aws" {
access_key = "${var.access_key}"
secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
region = "us-east-1"

}
resource "aws_iam_role" "replication" {
name = "tf-iam-role-replication-12349995"

assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
 {
 "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
 "Principal": {
 "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
 },
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Sid": ""
 }
 ]
 }
 POLICY
 }
```

vars.tf

```
variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}
```

on running

```
steps {
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
credentialsId: 'Source', 
secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

sh "  sudo terraform init ; sudo terraform plan -var 'access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'  -var 'secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'"
}
}
}
```

Terraform init is working fine but terraform plan is giving error.

```
+ sudo terraform plan -var access_key=**** -var secret_key=****
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.aws: plugin exited before we could connect
```

This script is working fine in Vagrant VM without jenkins

Comment: General points: there's usually no need to run `terraform` with sudo. Further, you don't have to supply the AWS credentials into the `provider` - the AWS provider should automatically read the well-known `AWS_` environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Which Terraform version are you using?

Have you tried those parameters:

- terraform init -input=false
- terraform plan -input=false
- terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve